# Github-Pages error running Jekyll Locally

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to run my Github-pages website locally. I have it running on another machine that is using Ruby 2.1.0 on Windows x64. Today I wanted to run locally on my home machine that is running Ruby 2.2.0. I pulled my repo locally, ran `bundle install` after a few issues with nokogiri I was able to get through a clean `bundle install`. I then proceeded to run the command `bundle exec jekyll serve -w`. Upon running this command I receive the following errors:

```
/Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander 4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:385:in block in require_program': program version required (Commander::Runner::CommandError)
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in `each'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:384:in require_program'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:52:in run!'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:8:in run!'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global/gems/commander-4.1.6/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in block in <top (required)>'
/Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:43:in <module:SafeYAML>': undefined method tagged_classes' for Psych:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:26:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:1:in require'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in require'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/lib/jekyll.rb:21:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/bin/jekyll:7:in require'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/jekyll-1.5.1/bin/jekyll:7:in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in load'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in <main>'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from /Users/<me>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in <main>'
```

I'm beginning to believe that this issue is not to do with my setup but with an incompatibility with jekyll on ruby 2.2.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

So after some more digging I was missing a simple step. After running the command `bundle install` I needed to run `bundle update`. Once I did this the version of jekyll and other dependencies was brought up to the correct version and I was then able to run my `bundle exec jekyll serve -w` command without any errors.

This seems strange that the initial install command would not install the latest version.

Comment: Cool. The problem is actually caused by the `safe_yaml` gem 1.0.3. The subsequent version, 1.0.4 fixes it, which is what `bundle update` does. :)